text не обрабатывается
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, Router, types
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command
from aiogram.filters.text import Text  # Импорт Text
from aiogram.types import Message, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from googletrans import Translator

API_TOKEN = ''

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher()

router=Router()


dp.include_router(router)

translator=Translator()

@router.message(CommandStart)
async def cmd_start(message:Message):
    await message.answer("/nПривет я бот-переводчик.Напишите текст который  надо перевести и на какой язык.")
    await message.answer("Например: 'Привет, мир! en ' ")

@router.message(Text)
async def translate_text(message:Message):
    text_to_translate = message.text.split(" ", 1 )
    if len (text_to_translate) == 2:
        text=text_to_translate[0].strip()
        target_language = text_to_translate[1].strip()
        try:
            translation = translator.translate(text, dest=target_language)
            await message.answer(f"Перевод на{target_language}:\n{translation.text}")
        except ValueError:
            await message.answer(f"Неверный код языка.Пожалуйста , введите правильный код языка.")
        else:
            await message.answer(f"Пожалуйста, введитее текст и код языка для перевода.")
async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())




    


Там, где Вы импортируете роутер, импортируйте ещё фильтры: from aiogram import F. Теперь вместо @router.message(Text) укажите @router.message(F.text)

теперь какая-то ошибкка то что бот постоянно повторяет  текст с команды старт

"Какая-то ошибка" - это какая? Я не могу так понять
